# MS Word 2013: path to local copies

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2013

I am using Microsoft Word 2013

Because I have a network share which is somewhat unreliable, I enabled the following option in  File=> Options => Advanced :

`Copy remotely stored files onto your computer, and update the remote file when saving`

Where do the local copies get saved? How long are they saved for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/22dee818-6be9-4459-a01d-e17c85031a02/word-2010-copy-remote-files-locally-behavior?forum=word

So if you open the document from the original location on the network and then when you press Save and that location is not available, it will ask you where to have it locally.

> With this option selected and you open a file that is located on a
>   network share or removable drive, Word saves a copy of the file to
>   your local fixed hard disk drive. Word then uses the local copy of the
>   document as a working reference during the entire editing process
>   until you save your changes. During the save process, Word saves the
>   changes you made to the local working copy and also saves the changes
>   made back to the original document.
>
> As you may also have learnt, if the original file is not available,
>   Word will prompt you to save the file in another location.

Furthermore, you can check the **AutoRecover File Location** and the **Default File Location** for where Word 2013 saves files automatically on the local machine as per https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/887-word-auto-recover-file-location.html

> Step 1: In **Word 2010** and **2013**, click **File > Options >
>   Save**;

[image]

Comment: Thank you, does this mean, the file is stored in memory and only when remote location is not available, will ask you to store it locally?

Comment: @Alex I just put an update to my answer. You can test easily by opening the doc on your network and disconnect the network plug or whatever and then press save and see if it prompts or saves to one of those locations without the prompt.